# PHP soapClient xml soap envelope format error

Tags: php, soap

I call a method with php soapClient class, like this:
`$client->ResetAppPassword($request);`

and my envelope is send like this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.xxxx.com/PATH/TO/V1/schema"
xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ResetAppPasswordRequest>
            <ns1:username>TEST</ns1:username>
            <ns1:app>TEST</ns1:app>
        </ns1:ResetAppPasswordRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the server response:

The message must be an instance of: {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope

and this is because the service is specting other format:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sch="http://xmlns.xxxx.com/PATH/TO/V1/schema">
    <soap:Body>
        <sch:ResetAppPasswordRequest>
            <sch:username>TEST</sch:username>
            <sch:app>DMS</sch:app>
        </sch:ResetAppPasswordRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So the i already tried to send it via `php-CURL` but with this solution I need to parse the XML response, so this make the process really hard, because I want to manage the response as an object.

Can someone help me... PLEASSSE..